# How to get "1" if value last in "OVER(order by something)" group, and "0" if not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have simple query with window function:

```
select
    productId, 
    is_last = row_number() over( order by productId ) 
from [productstatuses] order by ProductID
```

How can i modify "is_last" to get 1 as value if current record is last in "over(order by productId )" group and 0 if not?

**UPDATE:** Thank's to @TechDo , the final solution for my problem is:

```
select
    productId, 
    is_last = iif(count(*) over(order by productId)=row_number() over(order by productId), 1, 0)
from [productstatuses] order by ProductID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
select
    productId, 
    is_last = case when COUNT(*) OVER()=row_number() over(order by productId) then 1 else 0 end
from [productstatuses] order by ProductID
```

Comment: Thank you!  Count also must by OVER'ed with "(order by productId)" to get result that i need. And it works! :)